# Needing jQuery listener for input field - keyup and change not working

Tags: jquery

I need to enable a submit button on my form once the user enters some text into the email address field. Problem is they may be on the form for the second or third time, and the browser saves their email addresses in a drop-down menu under the input.

See here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaZWE.jpg

When they click that, it doesn't  work. How can i get jquery to listen for that as well?

Comment: just to be clear, "it doesn't work" means that clicking the browsers's dropdown suggestion doesn't trigger my jQuery event, and I've tried using both .keyup and .change

Comment: Sample code (especially via your live page or a trimmed-down version on something like jsfiddle.net) would certainly help to see how your events are actually bound.

Comment: @gregp: jsfiddle is simply tremendous, I'd never seen it before. Thank you for that idea! You can see it at http://jsfiddle.net/x2FaA/2/

The idea is that the checkout button only appears if track(s) are selected and an email address is entered. if you select tracks and type an email, it's working fine. but if you choose a pre-entered email from the dropdown, it doesn't enable the checkout button. Only when a character has actually been *typed* in the email field will the button enable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very strange. When I tried it yesterday with .change instead of with .keyup, it did not work. But today it is. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

check the email input box value of keydown event.